# Getting nullpointerException in oncreateView() in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-actionbar

Here I am new in `Fragment` and `ActionBar`.

I am using ActionBar to my Fragment class.but I am getting `NullPointerException` in this line

and also my Android version is Google APIs [Android 4.0]

```
 actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

and I am using this API

```
public class TodaysDealFragment extends Fragment implements
ActionBar.TabListener{

private View myview = null;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;
// Tab titles
private String[] tabs = {"Mumbai", "Shopping", "Travel"};

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    myview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
    // Initilization
    viewPager = (ViewPager) myview.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
     System.out.println("amar actionBar is==="+actionBar);
       //actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

    // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

    /**
     * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
     * */
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });



return myview;  
}


@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, android.app.FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab arg0, android.app.FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(arg0.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0, android.app.FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



  }
```

This is my Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.test"
   android:versionCode="12"
   android:versionName="2.4" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:name="com.test.TestApplication"
    android:allowClearUserData="true"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    >

    <activity
        android:name="com.test.TestActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" 
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.test.ui.LoginActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
       >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.test.ui.DailyEmailActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.testi.YourOrderActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.test.LocationActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.test.TestSocialWebActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.test.TestWebActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>    
    <activity
        android:name="com.test.WalletWebview"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_wallet_webview"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Where have you initialized actionBar. post that part

Comment: post full code please

Comment: What is the theme applied to activity in manifest

Comment: which activity? this is my Fragment class

Comment: @AmarRaj post the manifest file. Fragment is hosted by a Activity

Comment: @Raghunandan  tell me the what is the solution for removing the nullpointerexception

Comment: @AmarRaj show me your manifest

Answer (score 1):

```
public ActionBar getActionBar ()

Added in API level 11
Retrieve a reference to this activity's ActionBar.

Returns

The Activity's ActionBar, or null if it does not have one.
```

`getActionBar()` returns null

`getActivity()` returns the Activity this fragment is associated with.

So it looks like you applied a theme that does not have actionbar

Edit:

Your problem confirmed by

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

Apply a theme that provides actionbar. Change to

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light"
```

Comment: @AmarRaj no you won't get NPE  and if you get so it cannot be the same that causes NPE. post the stacktrace

Comment: is it necessary to initialize Fragment in AndroidManifest file.because I am using ActionBar in Fragment class.

Comment: @AmarRaj only activities are declared in manifest. Fragments are attached to the Activity. Your understanding of `Activity` and `Fragment` is completely wrong